# How to exit from a submenu back to a main menu?

Tags: loops, menu, switch-statement, exit, submenu

**I have the following simple main menu without any methods called in it, and I'm lost at how to make the sub-menu exit back to the main menu when the exit option is chosen in each?** 
I'm quite the beginner and this project is quite important as if I fail I won't be able to do my exam despite having paid for it already :(

**The menu code (so far) is the following:**

*//The menu will consist of 6 listings being: Books, Members, Employees, Loans, Statistics, Exit.

//These listings from 1 to 4 will open a submenu consisting of: Insert, Search, Delete, Edit, List All, Exit.

//Listing 5 will consist of: Top 5 Books, Top 5 Members, Employee of the Month, List Overdues, Exit.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class Menu
      {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
      {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option; 

    do 
    { 
    System.out.println("Main Menu:"); 
    System.out.println("1. Books"); 
    System.out.println("2. Members"); 
    System.out.println("3. Employees"); 
    System.out.println("4. Loans");
    System.out.println("5. Statistics");
    System.out.println("6. Exit");
    System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5,6]:");
    option = sc.nextInt();

    switch (option) {
        case 1: System.out.println("Books Sub-Menu:");
                System.out.println("1. Insert"); 
                System.out.println("2. Search"); 
                System.out.println("3. Delete"); 
                System.out.println("4. Edit");
                System.out.println("5. List All");
                System.out.println("6. Exit"); 
                System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5,6]:");
                option = sc.nextInt();

                switch (option){
                    case 1:
                    case 2: 
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    option = sc.nextInt();
                    break;
                }
        break;

        case 2: System.out.println("Members Sub-Menu:");
                System.out.println("1. Insert"); 
                System.out.println("2. Search"); 
                System.out.println("3. Delete"); 
                System.out.println("4. Edit");
                System.out.println("5. List All");
                System.out.println("6. Exit"); 
                System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5,6]:");
                option = sc.nextInt();

                 switch (option){
                    case 1: 
                    case 2: 
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    option = sc.nextInt();
                    break;
                }
        break;

        case 3: System.out.println("Employees Sub-Menu:");
                System.out.println("1. Insert"); 
                System.out.println("2. Search"); 
                System.out.println("3. Delete"); 
                System.out.println("4. Edit");
                System.out.println("5. List All");
                System.out.println("6. Exit"); 
                System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5,6]:");
                option = sc.nextInt();

                 switch (option){
                    case 1: 
                    case 2: 
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    option = sc.nextInt();
                    break;
                }
        break;

        case 4: System.out.println("Loans Sub-Menu:");
                System.out.println("1. Insert"); 
                System.out.println("2. Search"); 
                System.out.println("3. Delete"); 
                System.out.println("4. Edit");
                System.out.println("5. List All");
                System.out.println("6. Exit"); 
                System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5,6]:");
                option = sc.nextInt();

                 switch (option){
                    case 1: 
                    case 2: 
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    option = sc.nextInt();
                    break;
                }
        break;

        case 5: System.out.println("Statistics Sub-Menu:");
                System.out.println("1. Top 5 Books"); 
                System.out.println("2. Top 5 Members"); 
                System.out.println("3. Emplyee of the Month"); 
                System.out.println("4. List Overdue");
                System.out.println("5. Exit"); 
                System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5]:");
                option = sc.nextInt();

                 switch (option){
                    case 1: 
                    case 2: 
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    option = sc.nextInt();
                    break;
                }
        break;

        case 6: System.out.println("You selected to Exit");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
    }

   }  while (option!=6);

    }
    }*
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid single variable to control two different switch. Here you used option variable to control both inner and outer switch. When  option is 6 then controls breaks from both switches. 
Use another variable to control inner loop. I used subOption in the following code.

Also submenu functionality should work until user wants to exit. So better to add do while inside inner switch also.

```
    public class Menu {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option, subOption;

    do {
        System.out.println("Main Menu:");
        System.out.println("1. Books");
        System.out.println("2. Members");
        System.out.println("3. Employees");
        System.out.println("4. Loans");
        System.out.println("5. Statistics");
        System.out.println("6. Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5,6]:");
        option = sc.nextInt();

        switch (option) {
        case 1: {

            do {
                System.out.println("Books Sub-Menu:");
                System.out.println("1. Insert");
                System.out.println("2. Search");
                System.out.println("3. Delete");
                System.out.println("4. Edit");
                System.out.println("5. List All");
                System.out.println("6. Exit");
                System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5,6]:");
                subOption = sc.nextInt();

                switch (subOption) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("in Insert");
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("in Search");
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("in Delete");
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    System.out.println("in Edit");
                    break;
                }
                case 5: {
                    System.out.println("in List All");
                    break;
                }
                case 6: {
                    System.out.println("in Exit");
                    break;
                }
                // option = sc.nextInt();
                }
            } while (subOption != 6);
            break;
        }

        case 2:

        {

            do {
                System.out.println("Members Sub-Menu:");
                System.out.println("1. Insert");
                System.out.println("2. Search");
                System.out.println("3. Delete");
                System.out.println("4. Edit");
                System.out.println("5. List All");
                System.out.println("6. Exit");
                System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5,6]:");
                subOption = sc.nextInt();

                switch (subOption) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("in Insert");
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("in Search");
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("in Delete");
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    System.out.println("in Edit");
                    break;
                }
                case 5: {
                    System.out.println("in List All");
                    break;
                }
                case 6: {
                    System.out.println("in Exit");
                    break;
                }
                // option = sc.nextInt();
                }
            } while (subOption != 6);
            break;
        }

        case 3:

        {

            do {
                System.out.println("Employees Sub-Menu:");
                System.out.println("1. Insert");
                System.out.println("2. Search");
                System.out.println("3. Delete");
                System.out.println("4. Edit");
                System.out.println("5. List All");
                System.out.println("6. Exit");
                System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5,6]:");
                subOption = sc.nextInt();

                switch (subOption) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("in Insert");
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("in Search");
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("in Delete");
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    System.out.println("in Edit");
                    break;
                }
                case 5: {
                    System.out.println("in List All");
                    break;
                }
                case 6: {
                    System.out.println("in Exit");
                    break;
                }
                // option = sc.nextInt();
                }
            } while (subOption != 6);
            break;
        }

        case 4:

        {

            do {
                System.out.println("Loans Sub-Menu:");
                System.out.println("1. Insert");
                System.out.println("2. Search");
                System.out.println("3. Delete");
                System.out.println("4. Edit");
                System.out.println("5. List All");
                System.out.println("6. Exit");
                System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5,6]:");
                subOption = sc.nextInt();

                switch (subOption) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("in Insert");
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("in Search");
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("in Delete");
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    System.out.println("in Edit");
                    break;
                }
                case 5: {
                    System.out.println("in List All");
                    break;
                }
                case 6: {
                    System.out.println("in Exit");
                    break;
                }
                // option = sc.nextInt();
                }
            } while (subOption != 6);
            break;

        }

        case 5: {

            do {
                System.out.println("Statistics Sub-Menu:");
                System.out.println("1. Top 5 Books");
                System.out.println("2. Top 5 Members");
                System.out.println("3. Emplyee of the Month");
                System.out.println("4. List Overdue");
                System.out.println("5. Exit");
                System.out.println("Enter your option [1,2,3,4,5]:");
                subOption = sc.nextInt();

                switch (subOption) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("in Top 5 Books");
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("in Top 5 Members");
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("in Emplyee of the Month");
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    System.out.println("in List Overdue");
                    break;
                }

                case 5: {
                    System.out.println("in Exit");
                    break;
                }
                // option = sc.nextInt();
                }
            } while (subOption != 6);
            break;

        }

        case 6:
            System.out.println("You selected to Exit");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }

    } while (option != 6);

  }
}
```